# How to fill vertical space with flexbox in Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to create a series of rows that scale to fit the available screen space. This seems to be necessary to create a decent UI on a mobile device, as it prevents all the boxes from clustering at the top, and spaces rows evenly. The problem is that it appears to be ignoring the vertical fill on the container, and gathering elements at the top. My code is as below

CSS:

```
.fill-vertical-space{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: green;

    height: 100%;
}

.fill-vertical-space > div, .fill-vertical-space > .row{
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="fill-vertical-space">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="col col-100 section">
             ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "row">
        <div class="col col-100 section">
                ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: I have left the content out of the rows. They are typically a mix of heading, nested flex boxes, and drop down menus.

Note 2: I have looked at other answers on the site, but none of them relate to ionic specifically (Could it be possible that Ionics CSS interferes with flex box?).

Comment: If you can use Codepen or [ionic](http://play.ionic.io) to create a demo, that would be good.

Comment: I will take a look at it. Might not have time today, but I understand that it will be helpful.

Comment: Created a code pen example. i have been playing with this code a lot. This same code doesn't seem to work within the ionic framework. http://codepen.io/adzy2k6/pen/xwVaJe?editors=110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was down to an ionic class in their CSS file. Adding:

```
.scroll{
    height: 100%;
}
```

fixed the issue. I also needed an outer container holding the flex module, that was also set to 100% height, and to declare the .fill-vertical-space class as having static positioning.

Comment: Proven. The exact same setup works perfectly for me. :)